# printstream losing characters after slash

Tags: java, ide, groovy, intellij-idea, iostream

I'm doing something like this

```
PrintStream actualStdout = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out))
```

and then all of my logging is like

```
actualStdout.println(message)
```

(don't ask why)

I see a problem in my IDE when I try to print a string with slashes, such as a url.

http://somehostcom/somepath
comes out as
http:/somehost.com/omepath

Comment: @Kallin Nagelberg is the message your printing out have backward slashes? \

Comment: I just copy-pasted your example, and does not behave as you describe

Comment: I tried it as well, and it worked fine

Comment: You have to start the programme in debug mode to see what happened because it seems normal for me

Comment: Are you actually using Java? Neither line of sample code ends with a semicolon, which disturbs me.

Comment: It would disturb me too, but it's groovy so basically java.

Comment: It's interesting, I only see the problem while running in Intellij. When I run as a unit test through Gradle I get the expected output in the logs.

Comment: I'm peering into printstream in debug mode to see whaguan

Comment: I can't seem to debug deeper than printstream, and everything looks fine until then. I've worked around the issue by doing a check for an intellij system property when, if present, it just does a regular println.

Comment: So basically, whenever a slash appears, the next character is lost. It sounds to me like something is using the slashes for escaping, but that doesn't seem logical.

Comment: That's sort of what I figured, probably something to do with the way Intellij is treating slashes in it's display. Why system.out.println would be different that through the printstream is beyond me.